# How can I extact the few entries based on certain conditions?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, parsing

I have a data in the following format.

```
>ab:xy_a0by98-2 \Movie= top gun \actor= Tom \Genere=Action \Length=234 \Credits=30 \pe=1 \summry=(Tom|action|234)
Top Gun is a 1986 American action drama film directed by Tony Scott, and produced by Don Simpson and Jerry Bruckheimer

>ab:xy_b0ha81-5 \Movie= Thor \actor= chris hemsworth \Genere=Action \Length=321 \Credits=20 \pe=0 \summry=(chris|Action|321)
Thor embarks on a journey unlike anything he's ever faced a quest for inner peace

>ab:xy_c0ma65-1 \Movie= Batman \actor= Bale \Genere=Action \Length=251 \Credits=30 \pe=1 \summry=(Bale|Action|251)
From American Psycho to Batman Begins to Vice, Christian Bale is a bonafide A-list star
But he missed out on plenty of huge roles along the way.

>ab:xy_d0fc78-2 \Movie= Joker \actor= Phoenix \Genere=thriller \Length=341 \Credits=35 \pe=2 \summry=(phoenix|thriller|341)
Joker is a 2019 American psychological thriller film directed and produced by Todd Phillips
who co-wrote the screenplay with Scott Silver

>ab:xy_e0ra81-2 \Movie= Superman \actor= henry cavill \Genere=Action \Length=254 \Credits=28 \pe=1 \summry=(cavill|action|254)
Henry William Dalgliesh Cavill is a British actor
He is known for his portrayal of Charles Brandon in Showtime's The Tudors
```

I want to extract all the entries which contain pe=1, each entiry starts with the `>` symobol as follows:

```
>ab:xy_a0by98-2 \Movie= top gun \actor= Tom \Genere=Action \Length=234 \Credits=30 \pe=1 \summry=(Tom|action|234)
Top Gun is a 1986 American action drama film directed by Tony Scott, and produced by Don Simpson and Jerry Bruckheimer

>ab:xy_c0ma65-1 \Movie= Batman \actor= Bale \Genere=Action \Length=251 \Credits=30 \pe=1 \summry=(Bale|Action|251)
From American Psycho to Batman Begins to Vice, Christian Bale is a bonafide A-list star
But he missed out on plenty of huge roles along the way.

>ab:xy_e0ra81-2 \Movie= Superman \actor= henry cavill \Genere=Action \Length=254 \Credits=28 \pe=1 \summry=(cavill|action|254)
Henry William Dalgliesh Cavill is a British actor
He is known for his portrayal of Charles Brandon in Showtime's The Tudors
```

and to format few values in a table as:

```
Name            Length
ab:xy_a0by98-2  234
ab:xy_c0ma65-1  251
ab:xy_e0ra81-2  254
```

I tried `grep "pe=1" input.txt > output.txt`. But it has extarcted only the first line not the description.
Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***1st solution(With GNU `awk`):*** With your shown samples please try following in `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Simple explanation would be, checking if line starts with `>` and having `\pe=1` AND using `match` function to match regex `\\Length=([0-9]+)`
and get its matched value into a capture group into array named `arr` to get needed value of Length string. If both of these conditions are TRUE then; printing 1st field followed by 1st item of array arr.

```
awk '/^>.*\\pe=1 / && match($0,/\\Length=([0-9]+)/,arr){print $1,arr[1]}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution(with any `awk`):*** With any version of `awk` please try following code, little tweak of 1st solution.

```
awk '
/^>.*\\pe=1 / && match($0,/\\Length=[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*=/,"",val)
  print $1,val
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you!!. The solution is working fine. Is there a way to subset the main data with description to a new file (as given in the first part of the question)

Comment: @batman, ok so you mean you as a 2nd question you want to get complete lines starting from `>` and having pe=1 correct?

Comment: Yes correct. I require like that.. Thanks

Comment: @batman, try like: `grep -E '^>.*\\pe=[0-9]+' Input_file >outfile` should help for 2nd one.

Comment: only first line is printed. I require the description also. For example, These part of `>ab:xy_a0by98-2` is not printed.
`Top Gun is a 1986 American action drama film directed by Tony Scott, and produced by Don Simpson and Jerry Bruckheimer`

Comment: @batman, you want to print line starting from > and it's next line also?

Comment: if you use `RMATCH+8,RLENGTH-8`, then val can be used directly. You return lines that start `>` unlike the sample output. You could fix this with `-v RS">"`

Comment: yes... all the lines before the next `>` starts

Comment: @batman, I would like to request you to please open a new question for that one. Its always recommended on SO 1 post 1 question only else future users/readers may get confuse, you could open a new question and we could discuss there for sure :)

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` command should do the job:

```
sed -n 's/^>\([^[:blank:]]*\).*\\Length=\([0-9]*\).*\\pe=1.*/\1 \2/p' file
```